# Why is the size of the union greater than expected?

Tags: c++, unions, bit-fields

```
#include <iostream>
    typedef union dbits {
        double d;
        struct {
            unsigned int M1: 20;
            unsigned int M2: 20;
            unsigned int M3: 12;
            unsigned int E: 11;
            unsigned int s: 1;
        };
    };
    int main(){
        std::cout << "sizeof(dbits) = " << sizeof(dbits) << '\n';
    }
```

output: `sizeof(dbits)  = 16`, but if

```
    typedef union dbits {
        double d;
        struct {
            unsigned int M1: 12;
            unsigned int M2: 20;
            unsigned int M3: 20;
            unsigned int E: 11;
            unsigned int s: 1;
        };
    };
```

Output: `sizeof(dbits)  = 8`

**Why does the size of the union increase?**

In the first and second union, the same number of bits in the bit fields in the structure, why the different size?

I would like to write like this:

```
typedef union dbits {
    double d;
    struct {
        unsigned long long M: 52;
        unsigned int E: 11;
        unsigned int s: 1;
    };
};
```

But, sizeof(dbits) = 16, but not 8, Why?
And how convenient it is to use bit fields in structures to parse bit in double?

Comment: Probably the compiler doesn't want `M2` to be split between two adjacent uints, so it skips 12 bits and places it entirely in the second uint.

Comment: What is the size of unsigned int on your machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

members of a bit field will not cross boundaries of the specified storage type. So

```
        unsigned int M1: 20;
        unsigned int M2: 20;
```

will be 2 `unsigned int` using 20 out of 32 bit each.

In your second case 12 + 20 == 32 fits in a single `unsigned int`.

As for your last case members with different storage type can never share. So you get one `unsigned long long` and one `unsigned int` instead of a single unsigned long long as you desired.

You should use `uint64_t` so you get exact bit counts. `unsigned int` could e anything from 16 to 128 (or more) bit.

Note: bitfields are highly implementation defined, this is just the common way it usually works.